# Spring boot: How to convert a 2 dimensional array of dynamic JavaScript Objects into Kotlin

Tags: java, json, typescript, spring-boot, kotlin

I am trying to send this JSON object to a Spring boot application in Kotlin.
It is a 2 dimensional array of objects that each contain a key that is a string and a value that is an integer like so:

```json
    [
            [
                {
                    "-1": 272
                },
                {
                    "2": 0
                },
                {
                    "apple": -1
                },
                {
                    "apple": -1
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "1": 20
                },
                {
                    "-1": 2
                },
                {
                    "orange": 1
                }
            ]
        ]
```

I am trying to conceptualize what kind of DTO I need to make in order to map this to an entity in the API. The object's type in the frontend is:

```js
interface Thing {
[item: number | string]: number
}
```

I have tried to use a Kotlin `List<List<Any>>` but I am having trouble accessing the key in order to get its value because it is dynamic. I have also tried to map this to a Kotlin `Pair<Any, Integer>` but Spring boot is still having trouble mapping this using ObjectMapper.

Answer (score 0):

The type would be list of list of map. Following code works

```
val result: List<List<Map<String,String>>> = objectMapper.readValue("""[
        [
            { "-1": 272 },
            { "2": 0 },
            { "apple": -1 },
            { "apple": -1 }
        ],
        [
            { "1": 20 },
            { "-1": 2 },
            { "orange": 1 }
        ]
    ]
""", object: TypeReference<List<List<Map<String,String>>>>(){})
```

Note that the key in JSON is always a string. You have explicitly check whether the key is Int (may be with `toIntOrNull`).
Also, by default, a JSON object always maps to `Map` in Java/kotlin instead of `Pair`